# Injecting cache as a dependency in Laravel 5

Tags: caching, laravel-5

I'd like to get away from using the Cache facade and inject it into my controller using the constructor, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store;

...

protected $cache;

public function __construct(Store $cache)
{
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

I'm then using an app binding in AppServiceProvider.php.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store',
        'Illuminate\Cache\FileStore'
    );
}
```

However, I get the following error because FileStore.php expects $files and $directory parameters in the constructor.

**BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 872:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [  $directory ]] in class Illuminate\Cache\FileStore**

Any idea how I would get around this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use the equivalent of the `Cache` facade you should inject `Illuminate\Cache\Repository` instead:

```
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as CacheRepository;

// ...

protected $cache;

public function __construct(CacheRepository $cache)
{
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

You can look up the underlying classes of facades in the documentation:

[Facades - Facade Class Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#facade-class-reference)

Comment: Thank you! I wish the Laravel documentation would expand on how to inject services rather than relying on facades for the more advanced developers. Comes in handy when you're trying to extract modules into packages.

Comment: If only they could use the bound class name instead of the string alias (`Illuminate\Cache\Repository ::class` instead of `cache.store`) in the framework code. Everything would be easier if I could jump into the Facade, see the class referenced there, and inject that.